# Jquery resizable textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery re-sizable textarea. Everything is working fine but on left click it does not focus the textarea. Right click work for focus and cursor movement but left click isn't working. I want to focus the textarea by left click or click.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/princefiddle/78KFk/4/)**

HTML:-

```
<div class="drag-item item-txt txt-static" id="1>" style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; top:50px; left:10px; z-index:50;">
 <textarea style=" width:98px; height:48px;" name="text" id="text">Some text</textarea>
```

JS:-

```
$(function () {
$('.drag-item').draggable({
                snap        : true,
                cursor      : "move",
                delay       : 100,
                scroll      : false,
                cancel: "text",
                containment : "parent",
               drag: function(e, ui){
                   //some code
                }
            }).resizable({
                containment : "parent",
                stop: function(e, ui) {
                    var width = ui.size.width;
                    var height = ui.size.height;
                    var hereDrag = this;

                    if($(hereDrag).find('textarea').length > 0){
                        $(hereDrag).find('textarea').css('width', width - 10);
                        $(hereDrag).find('textarea').css('height', height - 10);
                    }
                },
                resize: function(e, ui){
                   //some code
                }
            })
```

});

CSS:-

```
div {
    float: left;
}
#droppable {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    border:3px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the entire `div` is used for dragging, so the `click` event is stopped from bubbling to the `textarea`. You need to use a `handle` to do the dragging instead. Try this:

```
$('.drag-item').draggable({
    handle: '.drag-handle',
    // other settings...
})
```

```html
<div class="drag-item item-txt txt-static">
    <div class="drag-handle"></div>
    <textarea style=" width:98px; height:48px;" name="text" id="text">Some text</textarea>
</div>
```

Note you can make the `.drag-handle` appear however you need, I just made my example for speed.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/78KFk/6/)

Answer (score 0):

use this JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('.drag-item').draggable({
                    snap        : true,
                    cursor      : "move",
                    delay       : 100,
                    scroll      : false,
                    cancel: "text",
                    containment : "parent",
                    drag: function(e, ui){
                       //some code
                    }
                }).resizable({
                    containment : "parent",
                    stop: function(e, ui) {
                        var width = ui.size.width;
                        var height = ui.size.height;
                        var hereDrag = this;

                        if($(hereDrag).find('textarea').length > 0){
                            $(hereDrag).find('textarea').css('width', width - 10);
                            $(hereDrag).find('textarea').css('height', height - 10);
                        }
                    },
                    resize: function(e, ui){
                       //some code
                    }
                });

    $('.drag-item').click(function(){
        $("#text").focus();
    });

});
```

Working for me in fiddle.